# Not all key codes are working with cy.realPress() method - keyboard navigation is not working

Tags: cypress

I am trying to mimic the keyboard navigation in my Cypress test. I found a nice lib https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events#cyrealpress.

The method `realPress()` is working partially: not all key codes from https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events/blob/main/src/keyCodeDefinitions.ts are processing in my web application. Only `cy.realPress('Tab')` and `cy.realPress('Enter')` are working as expected - the cursor is focusing on the "next" element after `Tab` and the menu is opening after `Enter`.

But when I try to navigate as I am doing manually by keyboard (for example, using `cy.realPress('ArrowDown');` ) then the page is not scrolling. The same result is with other arguments:

1. `cy.realPress('ArrowUp');`
2. `cy.realPress('End');`
3. `cy.realPress('Home');`

Could you please give some advice on how to fix it?